# How to remove dashes(-) in string in B2C custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In B2C custom policy I have clientID with format e8023a66-30ed-4e31-a17e-c013081704a0 but I want to transform it to e8023a6630ed4e31a17ec013081704a0 that means need to removing dashes(-) in clientID. Please let me know the way to do that. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use a [StringReplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#example-of-stringreplace).

You can use this to remove the "-" characters.